# How can we get a topology satisfiying those properties?

Tags: general-topology

Assuming $X$ is a set, if we have a mapping $d^* : \mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X) $ satisfying:

1. $d^*(\varnothing)=\varnothing$
2. $x\notin d^*(\{x\},\forall x\in X$
3. $d^*(A\cup B)=d^*(A)\cup d^*(B),\forall A,B\subset X$
4. $d^*(d^*(A))\subset A\cup d^*(A),\forall A\subset X$

then,there is a unique topology $\mathcal{T}$,s.t.
$$A'=d^*(A),\forall A\subset X$$
where $A'$ is the derivation set of A.

I can't construct this topology, I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ for any subset $A$ of a topological space. So, a set $A$ is closed iff $A' \subseteq A$. In other words, a set $A$ is open iff $(X \setminus A)' \subseteq X \setminus A$.

Thus, define $$\mathcal{T} = \{A \subseteq X : d^*(X \setminus A) \subseteq X \setminus A\}$$
and prove that this works.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose you know the axioms for closed sets. Define $A\subset X$ to be closed if $d^*(A)\subset A$. Check that the axioms hold.

Remark: One more property of $d^*$ is needed: $A\subset B$ implies $d^*(A)\subset d^*(B)$.

See [Topology in terms of derived sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)#Topology_in_terms_of_derived_sets).

Comment: This property is implied by the 4 listed. If $A \subseteq B$, then $A \cup B = B$. Thus, $d^*(A) \subseteq d^*(A) \cup d^*(B) = d^*(A \cup B) = d^*(B)$.